# How to retrieve multiple times selected different item of ListView C#

Tags: c#, registry

I need to make an application in WinForm C# as my final programming project. The project is about managing Registry more nicely to make it easier for the user to edit values.

[image: How the program looks and the Registry Path I needed]

So I needed the *Registry Path* from the ListView in order to check if Value *UninstallString* exists. As you can see the label *Current uninstall option is:* updates according to the selected item (here it's the *Adobe Creative Cloud*). The problem is when I press again to select other program it crashes:

```
private void listInstalled_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        uninstall_optn.Enabled = listInstalled.Items.Count > 0;
        string retrieveAppPath = listInstalled.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[2].Text; //Error happens here: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'. Parameter name: index'
        retrieveAppPath = retrieveAppPath.Remove(0, 19);
        RegistryKey selectedAppPath = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(retrieveAppPath, true);
        if (ValueExists(selectedAppPath, "UninstallString"))
        {
            uninstall_crnt.Text = "Current uninstall option is: Enabled";
        }
        else
        {
            uninstall_crnt.Text = "Current uninstall option is: Disabled";
        }
    }
```

(I commented the line the error happens and the error).

Comment: `listInstalled.SelectedItems[0]` because you're in the process of a `SelectedIndexChanged` event.. guess who wins and `listInstalled.SelectedItems` will be `null` and or empty. If not, `SubItems` may not have an index of `2`.

Comment: Ok, that's a bit unclear for me. What do I need to change and what is the reason it doesn't work? (Sorry for being so hard, I'm just a bit new to it)

Comment: The selected index changed event will clear the `SelectedItems` and hence the reason for the error.

Comment: Oh, ok. Thanks for clarifying! How can I fix it? Can I reset it somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with this line you try access only one item

```
string retrieveAppPath = listInstalled.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[2].Text;
```

if you want to get list of all selected items try this

```
private bool _isUninstalEnabled;
        private List<string> _myUninstallList; //list contains all selected item path in your case 

    private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _myUninstallList = new List<string>();
        _isUninstalEnabled = listView1.Items.Count > 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < listView1.SelectedIndices.Count; i++)
        {
            string selectItemValue = listView1.Items[listView1.SelectedIndices[i]].SubItems[2].Text; //Registry path in your case
            _myUninstallList.Add(selectItemValue);

        }
    }
```

Comment: If I understand it right, it first saves the whole list's items path and then confirms whether it's enabled or not.

Comment: first it confirm then save data to list